# How would I create an opaque coloured box with transparent text on top of a video?

Tags: html, css, video, svg, frontend

I currently have this:

[A Screenshot of current "model"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpCYc.png)

The background is a video, so it is supposed to make the text appear "alive".

I've done this through SVG, how do I change the background from black to white? Fill-opacity doesn't seem to work with other colors than black.

If this isn't possible, is there anyway do this this through CSS or Javascript?

```
<video autoplay muted loop poster="../billeder/Blue-Horizon.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="../video/Blue-Horizon.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
<source src="../video/Blue-Horizon.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>





<svg viewbox="0 0 100 60">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="50">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="82" height="35" fill="#fff" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="51" y="35" dy="1" style="font-size:18px; font-weight: 900" opacity="1">SUMMER</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="5" y="15" width="95" height="30" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>    
</svg>
```

Comment: "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. " 

I didnt expect my first comment on this community to be that inconsiderate.. I actually have a running website with the current code, i just attached a screenshot because i thought that would be enough for people who know what to do.

Im sorry i didnt express my self clear enough or follow specific guidelines.. i guess this being the first post should flag that im new..

Comment: I'm sure it wasn't meant to be inconsiderate, it's a pretty standard comment for new posters that don't provide enough information to give a bit of guidance.

Comment: I just thinks its pretty harsh and arrogant to suggest that I should do some "research" and to "at least make an attempt" - I've googled for hours and cant find a working solution and i have a running website.. im pretty sure that what i provided  in post should be enough for a person that reads it and has the answer, i might be wrong though. in that case, i apologize. Im just disappointed with the tone of the first comment to a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the rect to be white, set its fill to white.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 60">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="50">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="82" height="35" fill="#fff" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="51" y="35" dy="1" style="font-size:18px; font-weight: 900" opacity="1">SUMMER</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="100" height="60" xlink:href="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/sea-water_1160-2.jpg"/>
  <rect x="5" y="15" width="95" height="30" mask="url(#mask)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.5"/>    
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robert. have a nice weekend.